# Need to know how to print annual donation statements for our donors

Tags: contributions, custom-reports

We are a church using CiviCRM.  We are at the time of year where we need to print out or email statements to our donors showing the tax deductible contributions they made so they can itemize these deductions on their tax returns.  How do I print individaul statements for these donors? Is there a way to sort this report so it will print all individual statements or would I have to run each report one at a time?  All donations have been properly input into the system and are ready to go.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Thank-You Letter.

1. Run a contribution report for 2016.
2. Select the individual(s) you want to create reports for
3. In the Actions dropdown, select "Thank-You Letters for Contributions"
4. Select your Grouping (I use Contact)
5. Select Your separator-- Comma will put all information into groups separated by commas, Table Cell will separate each contribution into it's own row (Table Cell is buggy)

Here is a very helpful posting about this
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-user-guide/blob/master/docs/contributions/manual-receipts-and-thank-yous.md

Somethings I have learned along the way:
1. The bugginess of the Table Cell option can be overcome with Foreach code. I can send you my code but we use LineItems with all our donations so it might not work so well for your setup.
2. There are limits of how many letters Civi can handle at one time. I think it is 600 and that may be due to the PDF generator limits.

Comment: Here is more info about the Table Cell Separator issue  http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15466/how-do-i-use-table-cell-separator-when-creating-thank-you-letters/16818#16818

Comment: I am on CiviCRM 4.7.15 and I don't see Thank You letter option in actions.